# Looking for repeated patterns in time series data

Tags: python, audio, statistics, time-series, fft

I have spent the best part of the last few days searching forums and reading papers trying to solve the following question. I have thousands of time series arrays each of varying lengths containing a single column vector. this column vector contains the time between clicks for dolphins using echolocation.

I have managed to cluster these into similar groups using DTW and want to check which trains have a high degree of similarity i.e repeated patterns. I only want to know the similarity with themselves and don't care to compare them with other trains as I have already applied DTW for that. I'm hoping some of these clusters will contain trains with a high proportion of repeated patterns.

I have already applied the Ljung–Box test to each series to check for autocorrelation but think i should maybe be using something with FFT and the power spectrum. I don't have much experience in this but have tried to do so using a Python package waipy. Ultimately, I just want to know if there is some kind of repeated pattern in the data ideally tested with a p-value. The image I have attached shows an example train across the top. the maximum length of my trains is 550.

[example output from Waipy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hrlev.jpg)

I know this is quite a complex question but any help would be greatly appreciated even if it is a link to a helpful Python library.

Thanks,

Dex

Comment: Why do you want to "test them with p-value"?

Comment: I guess it doesn't need to be a p-value. I'd just like a method that can determine if there is a train that has a repeated pattern so i can automate it for the thousands of trains.

Comment: Very interesting question, however, it's off topic here since it's not a specific programming question. Try stats.stackexchange.com or dsp.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Ah okay! i've now asked it over on stats exchange. I thought as it was python related it would be fine to ask here. I will leave it a few hours just in case before I delete it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone in a similar position I decided to go with Motifs as they are able to find a repeated pattern in a time series using euclidian distance. There is a really good package in Python called [Stumpy](https://stumpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which makes this very easy!

Thanks,

Dex

Comment: Please feel free to post any STUMPY questions to our Github Discussions: https://github.com/TDAmeritrade/stumpy/discussions